# Does any of the Virto Commerce reports show profit?

Tags: virtocommerce

Is the system capable of calculating profit too?
From the sales performance report, I didn't see a profit column. So is it safe to say Virto Commerce doesn't cater for profit reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually create your own report quite easily. Simply download and open the report file in report designer, modify values and sql command used to generate report and upload it to the server. The process is described here: http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Working+with+Reporting+system

The other question is more business question on how the profit is calculated. You can for instance save the Cost price for each item in the order and then use that cost for reporting. It will require customization to the checkout process.